# Try/Catch - "Code style" question

Tags: c#, coding-style, try-catch

In general I want to make a code that makes a call an Execute function of a class which may throw an exception. My question is should I setup the class and should I extract the values from it within the try/catch or out side?

Option A:

```
neededValue V;

try
{
    MyClass C = new MyClass();
    C.SomeParam = XXX;
    C.Execute();
    V = C.SomeParam2;
}
catch
{
    //Clean up...
    //Log...
    //Throw new exception
}
```

Option B:

```
neededValue V;
MyClass C = new MyClass();
C.SomeParam = XXX;

try
{
    C.Execute();
}
catch
{
    //Clean up...
    //Log...
    //Throw new exception
}

V = C.SomeParam2;
```

I know both will work, but which is nicer and easiest to read?

Comment: The behavior is not the same. In the second case you just don't care about Execute() method success and failure. Also, use finally for cleanup. Also use codereview.stackexchange.com to improve working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say option B is easier to read and more practical because you will know later that the Execute can throw and Exception.

They are not the same, in option B if you handle the exception then your B variable will be set too and not only if your Execute succeeds.

And you should always specify with the catch block what kind of exception you are catching and so you can handle it and/or Log it correctly.

Answer (score 11):

hey those are NOT the same thing, in the first case `V = C.SomeParam2;` will never be executed in case of exception while in the second case it will always be executed.

More than that, your example of catch block usage is **deeply wrong**, always put the exception object after the catch and log somewhere with a logging framework what has happended, then react and handle the exception if you can, and only if it makes sense, or throw it or don't catch it at all and your calling code will catch it.

Comment: By "clean up" I meant logging and throw new exception (edit the question). I will take care of the logic (-: it's the style I'm worried about.

Comment: you should not throw a "new" exception, just do throw, not even throw e. then the answer is anyway to put inside the try block what should be executed only when no exception because an exception from line 2 will move program flow to catch and then will continue after the catch and line 3, 4 and following inside the try will NOT get executed ever...

Answer (score 2):

I would say option a is more readable. And is certainly how I would do it especially.

Answer (score 1):

Well both will work fine

But make use of second one if you wan to use `MyClass` object outside the try catch block.

and

In first one scope of `MyClass` object is upto try block only.

**So its depends on your requirement how you can use one of the two.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you should include in your try block all the code having to do with the small task you are trying to accomplish. However, sometimes you NEED to define certain variables before you enter the try block. For instance, you always want to define InputStreams and OutputStreams before the try block so you can close them in your finally block.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on basically one question. Do you want `V` to be assigned the value of `C.SomeParam2` if the `Execute` method fails, and throws an exception?

If you don't want it to be assigned when it fails, go for A, if you want it to be assigned regardless of how `Execute` turned out, go for B.

Comment: Because I throw a new exception in the "catch", there will be no assignment to `V` in both options.